# Add PictureBox next to another PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

When I click on the Colored PictureBoxes a Colored PictureBox is added to the mainPanel.

The next time I click the button the Next PictureBox should be added beside the previous one.
How do you get the Left and Width of the previously added PictureBox?

[image]

```
    private void Back_Openings(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int left = mainPanel.Left;
        int top = mainPanel.Top;

        PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
        var picture = new PictureBox            

        {
            Name = "back_PictureBox",
            Size = new Size(120, 20),
            Location = new Point(left, top),
            BackColor= p.BackColor,
            BorderStyle= BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
        };

        this.Controls.Add(picture);
        picture.BringToFront();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to **Add PictureBox next to another PictureBox**. To answer your specific question, *How do you get the Left and Width of the previously added PictureBox?*, one way is to do a `Linq` query on the `Controls` collection of `mainPanel`.

```
    int _mainID = 0;
    private void AddPictureBoxToPanel(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is PictureBox pbSrce)
        {
            var picture = new PictureBox
            {
                Name = $"back_picturebox_{_mainID++}",
                Size = new Size(120, 20),
                BackColor = pbSrce.BackColor,
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            };
            var last = mainPanel.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().LastOrDefault();
            if (last is null)
            {
                picture.Location = new Point();
            }
            else
            {
                // Does not wrap, and will eventually be outside the visible bounds.
                picture.Location = new Point(last.Bounds.Right, last.Top);
            }
            mainPanel.Controls.Add(picture);
            Text = $"ADDED: {picture.Name} {picture.Bounds}";
        }
    }
```

[image: screenshot]

This screenshot shows a second option that "may or may not" be suitable for your project, which is to use a `FlowLayoutPanel` and let it worry about all those things.

```
    int flowID = 0;

    private void AddPictureBoxToFlowLayoutPanel(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is PictureBox pbSrce)
        {
            var picture = new PictureBox
            {
                Name = $"back_picturebox_{flowID++}",
                Size = new Size(120, 20),
                BackColor = pbSrce.BackColor,
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            };
            flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(picture);
        }
    }
```

---

A third option would be to create your new `PictureBox` objects with a name that's meaningful, index-wise. Then you can use the `string` indexer of the `Controls` collection to retrieve the one you want.

```
    private void ShowByName(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var boxesByName = new List<PictureBox>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _mainID; i++)
        {
            var name = $"back_picturebox_{i}";
            boxesByName.Add(mainPanel.Controls[name] as PictureBox);
        }
        var message =
            string.Join(
                Environment.NewLine,
                boxesByName.Select(_ => $"{_.Name} {_.Bounds}"));
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
```

[image: popup]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the width of the picture to the left `Location` point, should do the trick. You've given the picture `Size(120, 20)`, which I assume means that your picture is 20 pixels tall and 120 pixels wide. You need to use the width. In order to make it work, you need to have a `count` integer, which is going to be equal to 0 at the start of the program, and is going to go up by 1 every time you create a new box. Then you are going to add the width of the boxes to the left starting point of the location, multiplied by the `count` variable. You shouldn't create and assign 0 to the `count` variable inside the code you've shown us, because you don't want to always create it with 0.

Then you will add it to the `location` multiplied by the `width` and then you should add 1 everytime you create a picture. Example like this:

```
    private void Back_Openings(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int left = mainPanel.Left;
        int top = mainPanel.Top;

        PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
        var picture = new PictureBox            

        {
            Name = "back_PictureBox",
            Size = new Size(120, 20),
            Location = new Point(left + (count*120), top),
            BackColor= p.BackColor,
            BorderStyle= BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
        };

        this.Controls.Add(picture);
        picture.BringToFront();
        count++;
    }
```

The changes compared to your code are 2. First one is added `+ (count * 120)` to the left location. That way your location will start 120 pixels to the right with every next picture added. Since `count` would be 0 at the start, it won't affect the first picture. The other change is adding `count++;` at the end, which will make sure that the `count` goes up every time.

Another way could be adding the `+ (count * 120)` to the left variable at the top of your code like this:

```
int left = mainPanel.Left + (count * 120);
```